# Jsp output error

Tags: java, linux, jsp, ubuntu, tomcat7

I wrote a form and its corresponding Jsp.The form fills out ok and on clicking the Submit button the form shows the table it is supposed to.But not a single `getRequest` is processed.Instead it just outputs the entire code on the webpage.I have added the jsp file to the webapps file and so there is no issue there.The code is as follows:

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Murach Chap4</title>
 </head>
 <%
 String firstname=request.getParameter("firstname");
 String lastname=request.getParameter("lastname");
 String email=request.getParameter("emailadd");
 String username=request.getParameter("username");
 String password=request.getParameter("password");
 String addmail=request.getParameter("addmail");
 String contactvia=request.getParameter("contactvia");
 %>
 <body>
 <h1>Thanks for joining us!</h1>
 <p>Here is the information that you entered</p>
 <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="1">
 <tr>
 <td align="right">First name:</td>
 <td><%= firstname %></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="right">Last name:</td>
 <td><%= lastname %></td>
 <tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="right">Username:</td>
 <td><%= username %></td>
 <tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="right">Email:</td>
 <td><%= email %></td>
 <tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="right">Contact via:</td>
 <td><%= contactvia %></td>
 <tr>
 </table>
 <%
    if (addmail!=null)
    {
 %>
        We will mail you!!
 <%
    }
 %>
 <%
    String[] selectedcount=request.getParameterValues("country");
    for(int i=0;i <= selectedcount.length-1;i++)
    {
 %>
    <%=selectedcount[i]%>
 <%
    }
 %>
<form action="check1.html" method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="Return">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The check1.html also works fine.The code outputs the table but doesn't store the firstname from the form and in the table it outputs <%firstname> instead of my name and the same for all the variable.I am not using any IDE and am trying to run it from the terminal.

Comment: your action should be another JSP or a servlet, not an html

Comment: A jsp can contain html tags

Comment: yes, a JSP can contain html tags

Comment: Yeah so thats what i did in this jsp file

Comment: scriptlet code would cause abnormal terminal usage.

Comment: How exactly? I am totally new to this..

Comment: What exactly the error is?

Comment: The error is they display the entire code along with the table.

Comment: I assume your JSP is working fine. The form won't send anything to the server. because you have nothing in it but a submit button. If you need to send something to server, you should put it inside the `form`.

Comment: The question marked as duplicate to this one suffers from a 503 error.I on the other hand have not suffered from it.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<form action="check1.html" method="post">
```

To:

```
<form action="check1.jsp" method="post">
```